# getting value of variable from anonymous function , final dosn't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to send a value I have in my outer scope to my function on button click,
but when I run in debug mode I see the value of the variable is empty although during the build of the button it had a value. here is my code:

```
try 
    {
        String name = album.getString("name");
        final String albumId = album.getString("albumID");
        Button btnAlbum = new Button(this);
        btnAlbum.setText(name);
        btnAlbum.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        btnAlbum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                GetImages (albumId);
            }
        });

        albumHolder.addView(btnAlbum);
    }
```

so what I mean is the variable: "albumId" which I am trying to pass to a function on the click event.

forgot to mention that my function is being called from within a for loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a local variable in an anonymous function. Try using a reference to a class field, like yourActivity.this.albumID

If you need to hold some data per widget you may use setTag on a view to hold an object, and getTag on your callback to retrieve it.

Comment: i have multiple albumId's because this function is in a for loop... i need that on button click it will send the album id to a function

Comment: well its not a widget its just a regular activity of an app, if i hold lets say an object of the array of id's i need i will still need an index to get the correct id from that array and again i will need a variable on my click event. so i will run into the same problem

Comment: no, a button is a widget. If you use an id per button then store the id on the button with setTag